# Java: update and render methods want to cast

Tags: java, particles

Writing this piece of code following a tutorial. I have no idea why the update and render methods are asking to cast to particle.get(i). I didn't think this would have to be done.

Is there something i am missing here? Guidance would be appreciated. (Marked areas of concern with "**" "**")

```
 package particles;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.Particle;

public class createparticles  extends JFrame {

    private ArrayList<Particle> particles = new ArrayList<Particle>(500);

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private int size;
    private int life;
    private Color color;
    private BufferStrategy bufferstrat = null;
    private Canvas render;


    public static void main(String [] args){

        createparticles window = new createparticles(450, 280, "Particles");

        window.pollInput();
        window.loop();
    }

public void pollInput() {
    render.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

        }

        public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

    });
}


    public createparticles (int width, int height, String title){

        super();
        setTitle(title);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        setResizable(false);

        render = new Canvas();
        render.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        int nHeight = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
        int nWidth = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
        nHeight /=2;
        nWidth /=2;

        setBounds(nWidth-(width/2), nHeight-(height /2),width, height);

        render.setBounds(nWidth-(width/2), nHeight-(height/2), nWidth, nHeight);

        add(render);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        render.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferstrat = render.getBufferStrategy();

    }


    public void loop() {

        while(true){

            update();
            render();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000/60);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void update() {

        Point p = render.getMousePosition();
        if(p !=null){
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
        }

        **for(int i = 0; i <=particles.size() - 1; i++) {
            if(particles.get(i).update())
                particles.remove(i);**
        }
    }

        public void render(Graphics g){
            Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillRect(x -(size/2), y - (size/2), size, size);

            g2d.dispose();
            do{
                do{

        bufferstrat.getDrawGraphics();
                    g2d.fillRect(0,0, render.getWidth(), render.getHeight());

                    renderParticles(g2d);

                    g2d.dispose();
                } while(bufferstrat.contentsRestored());
                bufferstrat.show();
            }while(bufferstrat.contentsLost());
        }

        public void renderParticles(Graphics g2d){

            **for(int i =0; i <= particles.size() - 1; i++){
                 particles.get(i).render(g2d);**

            }

        }

}
```

Comment: what's the two asterisks in **for(int i = 0; i <=particles.size() - 1; i++) {

Comment: What do you mean "cast to particle.get(i)"? You can't cast into a method call, and nothing will ask you to.

Comment: Was marking out where the errors show in eclipse. I'm not simple, i am aware that code can not be made bold.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes it is. "quick fix: add cast to particle.get(i)" I don't understand why?

Comment: @JamesO'Connor Probably because `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.Particle` doesn't have an `update()` method since you imported the wrong class, and the compiler is wondering if you want to cast it to something else. It's not asking you to cast to a method, just asking you to add a cast to your code.

Comment: Okay that was silly but i am still left with a render error.. Same situation as update()